# How to boot live Ubuntu from ISO on an encrypted LUKS partition

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, iso, luks

For a while I've been wanting to set up my ultimate everyday-carry USB drive, and my current setup is a hybrid MBR-GPT with EFI 32, EFI 64 and legacy BIOS GRUBs on a FAT32 partition that can also be used for unencrypted storage, and a LUKS version 1 partition that contains sensitive information as well as all the ISOs I'd like to be able to boot into from the drive. Now in GRUB2 I can `insmod luks;insmod ext2` and `cryptomount` the LUKS partition; then I can kick off the boot process as I would with any live USB. Of course, the boot fails because the initramfs can't access the ISO it's supposed to because there's no way for GRUB to hand over the encryption keys, so I get dropped into a busy-box initramfs shell. My question: what does the initramfs normally do during a live USB boot, and how can I manually take those same steps with my setup? So far I've managed to decrypt the partition in the initramfs and mount it, so I have access to the ISO - but I don't know where to go from there.

TL;DR: What steps does the initramfs take during a normal live USB boot, and how can I manually perform those same steps after first having unlocked the LUKS partition on which the ISO resides?

Here's my procedure to set up the USB drive `/dev/sda`:

```
# Overwrite critical regions to prevent leftovers of previous iterations interfering
dd bs=512 if=/dev/zero seek=0 count=2048 of=/dev/sda
dd bs=512 if=/dev/zero seek=124997632 count=2368 of=/dev/sda

# Set up GPT
sfdisk /dev/sda <<EOF
label: gpt
unit: sectors
1 : start=2048, size=124930048, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, name="travel"
2 : start=124932096, size=65536, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, name="travel_EFI"
3 : start=124997632, size=2335, type=21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649, name="travel_BIOS"
4 : start=124999967, size=314572800, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, name="travel_STORE"
EOF

# Set up MBR 
sfdisk -Y dos /dev/sda <<EOF
label: dos
1 : start=2048, size=124930048, type=0c, bootable
2 : start=124932096, size=65536, type=ef
3 : start=1, size=2047, type=ee
4 : start=124999967, size=314572800, type=83
EOF

# Wait for kernel to be notified of the changes we made
sleep 5

# Make FAT32 filesystem for GRUB
mkdosfs -n TRAVEL /dev/sda1
mkdosfs /dev/sda2

# Create mount points and mount created partitions
mkdir boot
mkdir efi
mount /dev/sda1 boot
mkdir boot/boot
mount /dev/sda2 efi

# Install 64-bit EFI GRUB
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --removable --no-nvram \
  --root-directory=boot \
  --boot-directory=boot/boot \
  --efi-directory=efi

# Install 32-bit EFI GRUB
grub-install --target=i386-efi --removable --no-nvram \
  --root-directory=boot \
  --boot-directory=boot/boot \
  --efi-directory=efi

# Install legacy BIOS GRUB
grub-install --target=i386-pc \
  --root-directory=boot \
  --boot-directory=boot/boot \
  /dev/sda

umount efi

# Create grub.cfg to drop into GRUB shell on boot
cat > boot/boot/grub/grub.cfg <<EOF
insmod efi_gop
insmod font
insmod gfxterm
insmod png
loadfont /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2
set gfxmode=auto
set gfxpayload=keep
terminal_output gfxterm
EOF

umount boot
```

After the above, I set up /dev/sda4 with LUKS1 (cryptsetup luksFormat --version luks1) and an ext4 filesystem, and transfer the Ubuntu ISO to it.

On boot in the GRUB menu:

```
insmod ext2
insmod luks
cryptomount hd0,gpt4
```

Then boot the live ISO as usual

Comment: Is there some reason you really want the ISO in the encrypted part of the drive? Its not exactly like the ISO are secret or confidential. I would just make another partition for the ISO outside of the LVM to make it easy to loop mount with grub.

Comment: @oldfred I'd ideally like for the ISOs to be stored in the encrypted part of the drive for two reasons: firstly, it makes it very difficult to alter them so as to compromise them without breaking them in the process. Secondly, I'd prefer to be able to keep the ISOs private - while Ubuntu might not be very controversial, I'd also like to be able to have a Tails ISO for when I go somewhere that doesn't have free access to the internet, which would need to be hidden in that case. But even if both of these reasons were irrelevant, I'd be interested in learning how to do it for learning's sake.